# Angularjs - ng-messages not refresh after clear file (using bootstrap-fileinput) in ng-file-upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-file-upload, ng-messages

Is there a way to truly delete\remove file from file input ?
example: i chose file, i get client side error (maxSize), that ng-messages display, but after i remove the file the ng-messages is still displayed
and when i send data to server he still send the deleted file.

even if i select other file i still see the error message.

i think that the problem is that model is not updating, is there a way to solve it?
I use the latest version Angularjs 1.4.4

code:

```
<input class="btn-greend"value="{{MemberSignUpModel.ButtonText}}" ng-click="signUp(MemberSignUpAttemptModel.Photo)" />

<div class="row-f clearfix">
            <div class="ip-file">
                <label for="memberPhoto">{{MemberSignUpModel.PhotoTitle}}</label>
                <input class="file-input" type="file" title="Select photo please" id="memberPhoto" name="memberPhoto" ng-required="false" ngf-max-size="{{MemberSignUpModel.Photo.MaxLength}}"
                        ngf-keep="false" ngf-multiple="false" ngf-select="" ng-model="MemberSignUpAttemptModel.Photo" 
                       ng-class="{true:'fgc-invalid'}[memberSignUpForm.memberPhoto.$invalid && memberSignUpForm.memberPhoto.$dirty]" />

                <span class="error" ng-repeat="serverError in MemberSignUpModel.ServerErrors" ng-if="memberSignUpForm.memberPhoto.$pristine && MemberSignUpModel.ServerErrors && serverError.ControlClientName == 'memberPhoto'">

                </span>
            </div>
```

Regards,
Gonen.